# Node js require doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, require

I am working on a node app, but node doesn't require my classes properly. Instead it returns '{}'.

In order to test what has been included I try to print out the 
'require "./core/template"', but it returns '{}':

```
require './core/template'

res.end util.inspect template
```

and when I replace this line with e.g. "res.end 'hello world'", I get the following error:

```
$ /Users/Filipe/Desktop/Smoothic/app.coffee:20
template.parse(template.render("head\n  title= pageTitle\n  script(type='t
                        ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'render'
  at Object.handler (/Users/Filipe/Desktop/Smoothic/app.coffee:13:27)
  at final_dispatch (/Users/Filipe/Desktop/Smoothic/node_modules/node-simple-router/lib/router.js:275:26)
  at Server.dispatch (/Users/Filipe/Desktop/Smoothic/node_modules/node-simple-router/lib/router.js:326:14)
  at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
  at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
  at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
  at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

So my only guess is that the file maybe isn't compiled to javascript yet, or the compiler has got a bug, but that wouldn't make any sense, because usually all files are compiled before there server starts running.

I would be so thankful for some help

**Here is my code:**

app.coffee:

```
http = require 'http'
util = require 'util'
Router = require 'node-simple-router'
cson = require 'cson'

# I'm trying to include this coffee class
template = require './core/template'

router = new Router()

router.get '/', (req, res) ->
  res.writeHead 200

  # This method is supposed to render jade and parse it to the 
  # client, but thats not the problem
  template.parse template.render """
                                  head
                                    title= pageTitle
                                    script(type='text/javascript').
                                      if (foo) {
                                         bar(1 + 5)
                                      }
                                  body
                                    h1 Jade - node template engine
                                    #container.col
                                      if youAreUsingJade
                                        p You are amazing
                                      else
                                        p Get on it!
                                      p.
                                        Jade is a terse and simple
                                        templating language with a
                                        strong focus on performance
                                        and powerful features.
                                 """

  # In order to test what has been included I try to print out the 
  # 'require "./core/template"', but it returns 'undefined'
  #
  res.end util.inspect template

http.createServer router
  .listen 8080
```

./core/template.coffee:

```
path = require 'path'
jsdom = require 'jsdom'

class Template
  constructor: (file) ->
    parse render file

  render: (file) ->
    content = switch path.extname file
      when '.html' then fs.readFileSync file
      when '.jade' then jade.renderFile file

  parse: (content) ->
    jsdom.env
      html: content
      scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"]
      done: (errors, window) =>
        $ = window.$
```

Comment: Try `template = new require './core/template'` http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either do a `module.exports = class Template` in your template.coffee and instantiate it using

```
Template = require "./template"
AppTemplate = new Template()
```

or instantiate the class on export like this

```
module.exports = new class PluginManager
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with coffeescript's hidden features, but you will need to do a `exports=Template` at the end of your template.coffee file as it is [described in the module doc of node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: Than you, I forgot to do that. But that doesn't fully solve the problem. The error is still "Template has no method 'render'" and when I print out the value of 'template = require "./core/template"' I get '[method: Template]' which is undefined